# Не могу отловить нажатие inline кнопки аiogram 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Структура папок:

```
-bot
--handlers
---key_handlers.py
--keyboard
---keyboard.py
-main.py
```

****main.py****

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from handlers import key_handlers
    
from lib import constant
    
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=constant.TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_routers(key_handlers.router)
    
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**keyboard.py**

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
    
def btn():
    menu_list = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка1", callback_data="one_btn")], // к примеру эта кнопка
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка2", callback_data="btn2"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка3", callback_data="btn3")],
    ]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=menu_list)
```

**key_handlers.py**

```
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.filters.text import Text
from aiogram.types import Message, ReplyKeyboardRemove
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
    
from keyboard.keyboard import btn, otherBtn
    
router = Router()
    
@router.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(
        "Текст",
        reply_markup=btn()
    )
    
@router.callback_query(Text('one_btn'))   // Запрос сюда не попадает
async def callbackTariff(callback: CallbackQuery):
    print("adasdasdasdsa")
    await callback.answer(
        "Текст",
        reply_markup=otherBtn()
    )
```

Пробовал через `@dp.callback_query, @...(Text(text=["one_btn"]))` так тоже обращался, но все бестолку, в примерах вроде подобное обращение, но все равно не получается.

Написано что `callback` улавливает и обрабатывает запрос от нажатой кнопки, важным идентификатором является text либо `callback_data`, но все же не понятно почему не получается

Answer (score 1):

`@router.callback_query` - ожидается что на вход придет CallbackQuery
Оно не имеет в себе message, чтобы воспользоваться фильтром Text
Находится там data которую нам как раз и нужно сравнить с нужным ответом

```
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'one_btn')
```